# How do I access an azure app service without public access through a virtual network?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I've created an app service that is closed to public access with VNet integration enabled.

I've connected it to the virtual network and connected to the VPN for that network.

When I try to open the site on my browser I get the following:

[image]

What step did I miss?

Comment: you can configure VNet Integration Required for App Service with Private Endpoints. private endpoints securely host internet applications which you don't want to access from the public internet

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I have created a virtual network, virtual network gateway, and created web app service connected to vpn like below:

[image]

Make sure to configure a private endpoint in web app like below:

***In your web app -> networking -> private endpoint.***

[image]

Add private endpoint integrated with private DNS zone.

[image]

In your private endpoint under settings -> DNS configuration you can check private endpoint connection like below:

[image]

Now, when I try to test my web app I got the same Error 403 as it considered a pubic network.

[image]

When I connected with my VPN client to the Azure network got results successfully like below:

[image]

***Reference***:

[How to Use Azure Private Endpoints to Restrict Public Access to WebApps (varonis.com)](https://www.varonis.com/blog/securing-access-azure-webapps) by *Neeraj kumar*

Comment: I followed your steps and my web app is still open to the internet. Can you tell me exactly which step ensures that your app is closed to the internet?